# How do you integrate an incrementing variable into a paragraph

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make an idle game rather like  [candy box](https://candybox2.github.io/candybox/). I will have a number at the side of the page which rises by one every second. However, the code shown below does not seem to be working. Could anyone tell me why it is not working; how to fix it and where they got their info from. Thank you in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var i = 0;

 function increment(){
    i++;
    document.getElementById('money').innerHTML = i;
 }

 setInterval(increment(), 1000);
</script> 
        <h2><u>The best game of the century</u></h2>
        <p>you have &#163;<span id="money"></span>.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's not working because you are calling `increment` in your call to `setInterval` --- EDIT: maybe wasn't clear enough: `setInterval` expects the definition of a function, but instead you are running the function, which runs it once instead

Comment: Which part isn't working? Do you get an error message? If so, what does it say?

Comment: Also, your HTML tags are wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. You are calling your script before the DOM is rendered, so at the point the script runs, there is no element with ID of `money`.
2. In your `setInterval` call, you only need the function name (`increment`) without the parentheses. Including the parentheses (as `increment()`) only calls the function at that specific moment, rather than referencing it to be called at each interval. (See [the Microsoft page on `setInterval`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741353(v=vs.85).aspx) for more detailed information.)

See this code:

```html
<h2><u>The best game of the century</u></h2>
<p>you have &#163;<span id="money"></span>.</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var i = 0;

  function increment() {
    i++;
    document.getElementById('money').innerHTML = i;
  }

  setInterval(increment, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: And why don't you need the parentheses?

Comment: @BramVanroy Thanks, I forgot that part. Included now.

Answer (score 3):

change `setInterval(increment(), 1000);` to  `setInterval(increment, 1000);`

Its not working because as per document https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval
it takes a function reference to be executed.. but calling the function increment() like this will only execute once and the return of that function will be used which will be null and not intended hope this clears it

```js
var i = 0;

 function increment(){
    //console.log(i);
    i++;
    document.getElementById('money').innerHTML = i;
 }

 setInterval(increment, 1000);
```

```html
<h2><u>The best game of the century</u></h2>
        <p>you have &#163;<span id="money"></span>.</p>
```

Comment: You may want to explain why this is necessary.